# Why does gmail API when using history.list method send message ids without the field what action has been preformed on them?

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

When using gmail API, history.list method we get "bare" message ids with no additional field from the fields in 'labelAdded', 'labelRemoved', 'messageAdded', 'messageRemoved'. Why is that? And is it possible that a new message has been added but when we use this method, the field messageAdded hasn't been used, so we receive it "bare" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [GMail history API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list), the list only contains the **id** and **threadId** fields.
It works this way because the objective of the *history* API is to provide you with the changes that happened in the mailbox, not its contents.

After you obtain the list from *Users.history: list* you need to call [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) or [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to get the full messages.

If the **messageAdded** field is empty, it means that no new messages were added after the last *historyId* you examined. You might have skipped some. Make sure that every time you query the API you internally store the last *historyId* you processed so you can resume from that point in the future and not lose any changes.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am aware of the purpose of the method to only inform you about the changes in the users mailbox, but what is the purpose of messages contained in the response, that have no label that defines what happened to them? There are sometimes several of them with the same id. Are they just byproducts that have no significance, so that I should just ignore them?

Comment: The **messages** field is supposed to work as a summary listing all the messages that had any changes, regardless of what the changes were. They may be duplicates of the specific fields that detail the changes, so you can safely ignore those and only check Added and Deleted.  
Several of them appear sometimes because it's showing each change progressively instead of just the current state of the message.